# bootstrap using make like a google material drop down menu issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on this form using `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta'. In this, I want to create the drop down menu as shown in the following image just like that in material design but I want to do this using bootstrap.I am  trying  to use this code ,but it's not working. Does anyone know how to make like this  dropdown menu. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

example image

[image]

```css
/* form starting stylings ------------------------------- */
.group      { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:45px; 
}
input     {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}
input:focus   { outline:none; }

/* LABEL ======================================= */
label      {
  color:#999; 
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label   {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}

/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.bar  { position:relative; display:block; width:300px; }
.bar:before, .bar:after  {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:#5264AE; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */
.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  width:100px; 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
```

```html
 <form>
    
    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>
      
    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    
  </form>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the dropdown's "work" or are you trying to fix the "style"?

Comment: sir, im try to make using bootstrap drop down menu,not working

Comment: You are trying to make a `select` out of a button element. That is in so many ways the wrong approach. Most of all because it has no proper fallback on mobile devices. Please try to achieve this using a proper `select`. Show us what you have tried/got and why it did not work and we will (probably) be able to fix it for you.

Comment: @JoostS sir ,i got your idea, and i made it , look my answer

Comment: Well done! Nice work.

Comment: @JoostS Sir, Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i made it

```css
/* form starting stylings ------------------------------- */
.group      { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:45px; 
}
input     {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}
select {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}
input:focus   { outline:none; }
select:focus   { outline:none; }
/* LABEL ======================================= */
label      {
  color:#999; 
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label   {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}
select:focus ~ label, select:valid ~ label   {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}
/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.bar  { position:relative; display:block; width:300px; }
.bar:before, .bar:after  {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:#5264AE; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}
select:focus ~ .bar:before, select:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */
.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  width:100px; 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}
select:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}
/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
    
    <div class="group">      
       <select class=" " id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>
      
    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    
    
  </form>
```

Answer (score 7):

To bring the Material feel to select, apply the below given styles to `select` tag

**CSS**

```
select{
    border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
   }
```

**Example**

```css
/* form starting stylings ------------------------------- */
.group      { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:45px; 
}


input     {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}
select {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;

}
input:focus   { outline:none; }
select:focus   { outline:none; }
/* LABEL ======================================= */
label      {
  color:#999; 
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label   {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}
select:focus ~ label, select:valid ~ label   {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}
/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.bar  { position:relative; display:block; width:300px; }
.bar:before, .bar:after  {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:#5264AE; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}
select:focus ~ .bar:before, select:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */
.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  width:100px; 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}
select:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}
/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
    
    <div class="group">      
       <select class=" " id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>
      
    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    
    
  </form>
```

**UPDATE**

Please make sure that you have included `popper.js`.
Bootstrap V4 dropdown requires the popper.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Working Demo**

You could see the working demo in [codepen.](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/dVgjgw)

Comment: In your answer, see the select menu. It looks like a default style. To make the select also look like material feel, add the above given "CSS" under the CSS heading.

Comment: Sir actually I need select menu,

Comment: @core, but your "select tag" looks like default style. If you apply "-webkit-appearance: none;" then you can customise the caret icon. Where the select tag also look like the material feel.

Comment: sir, but my option is select tag, you can re edit this i can accept as well

Comment: @core114, Did you need to customize  for "select tag" or  "Bootstrap dropdown". In you question you have added that bootstrap dropdown is not working.

Comment: @core114, Please check out my update, I have updated the solution for your dropdown issue.

Comment: Sir thanks for your time,  look my following  answer i need like this ,any way my issue is fixed

Comment: @core114, Okay fine. If you need any clarification,  Check out my Codepen link in the description, I have given the style as you mentioned in the image.

Comment: Sir, my attached image is a example image, look my answer ,I'm all ready done it

Comment: Okay that's fine.